# What does the "PLT" in PLT-Scheme (now called Racket) stand for?

Tags: racket

I'm curious: what does the "PLT" in PLT-Scheme (now called racket) stand for?  The closest I could come to an answer was that "“PLT” refers to the group that is the core of the Racket development team" on [this page](http://racket-lang.org/people.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No one is really sure but [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Racket_(programming_language)#What_does_PLT_stand_for.3F) might enlighten you.

---

**EDIT**

Because link only answers are never a good idea

PLT was never a defined acronym. Originally the designers were part of the Rice Universities **P**rogramming **L**anguage **T**eam, but once the team expanded past this the acronym no longer fit. Even having no full form, the name stuck around. (for a while, it's now Racket)

Comment: Because the `)` in the link confused the Markdown parser into thinking that was the end of the link.

Comment: Funny that - an odd ```)``` brace ruining a Scheme answer.

Answer (score 5):

PLT stands for "Programming Languages Team". The [team](http://www.cs.rice.edu/CS/PLT/) that originally created PLT Scheme (now Racket.)

Comment: That has not been cited. Its just a rumour. The creators were the programming language team of their university but its suggested to be an inside joke between them